# Binary Search Tree, allocating pointer to templated struct node

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct, and I'm trying to create an instance of a pointer to struct node.

here is my struct:

```
template<class T>
struct node{

    T value;
    struct node* lx;
    struct node* rx;
    struct node* f; 

};
```

and here is what I'm trying to instance:

```
struct node<int>* n;

n<int> =new node;
```

How can I instance a pointer to struct node? I need it for a Binary Search Tree (insert function using template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax

```
n<int> =new node;
```

should be

```
n = new node<int>();
```

Comment: Thanks, now it work! ehmmm... how can i close this post?(i'm new here)

Comment: @OrazioContarino Why do you want to close it? You can accept the answer if it was helpful for you. May be there are others researching what should be the right syntax.

Comment: ah ok sorry, i accepted your answer, thanks you again for your help.

Comment: @OrazioContarino De nada! That's all the site is about. Enjoy using it in the future ;) ...

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with that allocation. But you already declared `n` to be a pointer to a `node<int>` so the `<int>` part is not needed for the variable. You do however need to specify the complete type in the `new` operation, like

```
n = new node<int>;
```